# How can a C compiler be written in C?

Tags: c, compiler-construction, kernighan-and-ritchie

This question may stem from a misunderstanding of compilers on my part, but here goes...

One can find the following statement in the preface to the first edition of K&R (page xi):

> The operating system, *the C compiler*, and essentially all UNIX applications programs (including all of the software used to prepare this book) are written in C.

(my emphasis)

Here's what I don't understand: doesn't that C compiler have to be compiled itself before it can compile any C code? And if that C compiler is written in C, wouldn't compiling it require an already existing C compiler?!

The only way out of this infinite-regression conundrum (or chicken-and-egg problem) is that the C compiler written in C that K&R are referring to was actually compiled with an already existing C compiler that was written in a language other than C. The C compiler written in C then superseded the latter.

Or am I completely off?

Comment: Well, you start with one in assembly or whatever, and once you have that, it's possible to use it to make one in C and so on afterward.

Comment: C was first written in B which was a stripped down BCPL which was a stripped down Algol 60 I believe.  B was probably written in a macro assembler though.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

It's called [Bootstrapping](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29), quoting from Wikipedia:

> If one needs a compiler for language X to obtain a compiler for language X (which is written in language X), how did the first compiler get written? Possible methods to solving this chicken or the egg problem include:

1. Implementing an interpreter or compiler for language X in language
   Y. Niklaus Wirth reported that he wrote the first Pascal compiler in
   Fortran.
2. Another interpreter or compiler for X has already been written in
   another language Y; this is how Scheme is often bootstrapped.
3. Earlier versions of the compiler were written in a subset of X for
   which there existed some other compiler; this is how some supersets
   of Java, Haskell, and the initial Free Pascal compiler are
   bootstrapped.
4. The compiler for X is cross compiled from another architecture where
   there exists a compiler for X; this is how compilers for C are
   usually ported to other platforms. Also this is the method used for
   Free Pascal after the initial bootstrap.
5. Writing the compiler in X; then hand-compiling it from source (most
   likely in a non-optimized way) and running that on the code to get
   an optimized compiler. Donald Knuth used this for his WEB literate
   programming system.

And if you are interested, [here](https://github.com/mortdeus/legacy-cc) is Dennis Richie's first C compiler source.

Answer (score 11):

Usually, a first compiler is written in another language (directly in PDP11 assembler in this case, or in C for most of the "modern" languages). Then, this first compiler is used to program a compiler written in the language itself.

You can read this [page](http://www.cs.bell-labs.com/who/dmr/chist.html) about the history of the C language. You will see that it is also strongly linked to the UNIX system.

Comment: Be careful transporting 1970 truths to today. GCC switched to C++ :-)

Comment: Hmmm, GCC in C++... I'm a bit doubtful about that (and scared also! :-)).

Comment: http://gcc.gnu.org/gcc-4.8/changes.html  first line.

Answer (score 9):

See the Chicken and Egg section of the [Wikipedia page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bootstrapping_%28compilers%29):

If one needs a compiler for language X to obtain a compiler for language X (which is written in language X), how did the first compiler get written? Possible methods to solving this chicken or the egg problem include:

- Implementing an interpreter or compiler for language X in language Y. Niklaus Wirth reported that he wrote the first Pascal compiler in Fortran.
- Another interpreter or compiler for X has already been written in another language Y; this is how Scheme is often bootstrapped.
- Earlier versions of the compiler were written in a subset of X for which there existed some other compiler; this is how some supersets of Java, Haskell, and the initial Free Pascal compiler are bootstrapped.
- The compiler for X is cross compiled from another architecture where there exists a compiler for X; this is how compilers for C are usually ported to other platforms. Also this is the method used for Free Pascal after the initial bootstrap.
- Writing the compiler in X; then hand-compiling it from source (most likely in a non-optimized way) and running that on the code to get an optimized compiler. Donald Knuth used this for his WEB literate programming system.

Comment: Pascal cuoq... 
In the first point,language Y should have a compiler first,right?I think languages like Clojure were written in this way.Could you explain "Hand compiling"?

Answer (score 6):

It's perfectly ordinary for a compiler to be written in the language it compiles. One way to achieve this would be to write a complete compiler for language L in some other language, and then to write a new compiler for L in L. A more interesting approach would be to write a minimal compiler for a subset of L in some other language, and then use this minimal subset to improve the compiler, making it less minimal increasing the available subset of L. In this way, a complete compiler can be built.