# The algorithm behind js indexOf() method in JAVASCRIPT

Tags: javascript, algorithm, time-complexity

When solving https://app.codility.com/programmers/lessons/5-prefix_sums/genomic_range_query/ problem, I found out that using `indexOf` method gives us the favor of polynomial performance. But as mentioned [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf), if we use this polyfill to determine index of element, it generates time limit error. My concern is what is the exact implementation of `indexOf` method for which it can perform in constant time which I am guessing close or equal to`(0[1])`?

Comment: Your question seems to really be about the coding challenge. `indexOf` is not O(1). Try it with huge arrays... It is just that the internal implementation of that function is not typically coded in JavaScript, but in a lower level language like C, giving a much higher performance.

Comment: @trincot Thats something I was thinking of. Maybe its the  native C code giving a better performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`indexOf` does not run in constant time. It is expected that it runs much faster than a polyfill implementation in JavaScript. This is because the functions that are part of the JavaScript language (EcmaScript), are typically written in a lower level language like C or C++.

Here is a test that illustrates that `indexOf` does not run in constant time:

```js
// create a very long string aaaa...ab...bc...cd (etc)
let alpha = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz";
let s = Array.from(alpha, c => c.repeat(10000000)).join("");
// find each of the letters in this long string
for (let c of alpha) {
    let start = performance.now();
    s.indexOf(c);
    let end = performance.now();
    console.log(end-start);
}
```

See [What language is JavaScript written in?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005729/what-language-is-javascript-written-in) for what languages are used for implementing JavaScript, including functions like `indexOf`.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is just a range-minimum query problem, which can be solved with constant time complexity using sparse tables. But with the fact, that there are only 4 different values there is an easier way to solve it:

Pre-calculate the number of times each letter appears on each prefix (first n symbols). This preprocessing will be done in linear time. Then for your range check if there is, for example, A letter as follows: if the count of letters before the start is equal the count of letters before the end - then, there is no letter A in this range. Do the same for all 4 letters and pick the minimum.

Comment: I was not searching for ways to solve the problem. As the category says its a prefix sum problem, there are many other ways to solve it. However I was curious with the behind algorithm of `indexOf` method.