# Can we not see built-in constructor functions because they're written in different languages?

Tags: javascript

Am I right in thinking that we can’t actually **see** the body of built-in constructor functions - i.e. `String` - because it's written in different language(s)?

In the console it comes up as 'native code'.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "see". `"String" in window` is perfectly visible even if it was defined by the engine, no?

Comment: Do you mean the source code of these built in functions?

Comment: Seems this question is just about which language JavaScript implementations are written in, not specifically constructors? Dupe of [Which language is JavaScript written in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7005729/what-language-is-javascript-written-in)?

Comment: Another reason for not showing the code (if it's JS) is to prevent browser fingerprinting.

Answer (score 1):

Functions which appear as `[native code]` appear that way because they are exactly that: native code. Their content is written in the language the javascript runtime is written in (e.g. node is written in C++ and deno is written in Rust).

Comment: Not always, though. Some of these are (or were) written in JavaScript.

Comment: @Bergi Would those functions be displayed as `[native code]` ?

Comment: They could also be written in Torque or some other language. Narrowing it down to C++ and Rust is not true.